# Variational formulation for elliptic interface problem

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Where can I find a paper that deals with the following interface problem with variational methods? In particular, what is the correct variational formulation of the problem (that is, a  functional whose critical points are solutions of the problem) that takes the boundary/interface conditions into account?

> Consider an open (bounded) domain $U$ split in two non-overlapping subdomains: $U=U_1\cup U_2$, which share a common smooth  interface $\Gamma \in C^1$, and the following elliptic problem:
>   \begin{align*} -&\nabla ( A_1(x)\nabla u ) =f_1 \ &\text{ in } U_1\\
> -&\nabla ( A_2(x)\nabla u )=f_2 & \text{ in } 
> U_2\\
> & u=g  & \text{ on } \partial U \setminus \Gamma\\ 
> & \left[k \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right]_\Gamma = 0 \\
> & \left[u \right]_\Gamma = 0 
> \end{align*}
>   (where $[\cdot]_\Gamma$ denotes the jump across the interface and $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ is the normal derivative).

---

Related questions:

- [Elliptic interface problem without conditions on the interface](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320226/elliptic-interface-problem-without-conditions-on-the-interface)
- [Elliptic problem on a domain split in two subdomains](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319667/elliptic-problem-on-a-domain-split-in-two-subdomains)
- [Boundary condition for elliptic problems and domain decomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319715/boundary-condition-for-elliptic-problems-and-domain-decomposition/319723#319723)

Comment: You probably mean $u=g$ on $\partial\Omega$ without $\Gamma$, right? Otherwise there is too much boundary condition. (I ask this because $\Gamma$ _is_ part of $\partial\Omega$).

Comment: @JeanDuchon Yes, I mean that. Thank you.

Comment: But then this is a standard nonhomogeneous Dirichlet problem on (the interior of) $\Omega_1\cup\Omega_2\cup\Gamma$, and you just have to minimize $J(v):=\sum_{i=1}^2\int_{\Omega_i}[A_i(x)|\nabla v(x)|^2-f_i(x)v(x)]\ dx$ on $\{v\in H^1:u=g \ on\  \partial\Omega\setminus\Gamma\}$. Why not?

Comment: @JeanDuchon I want solutions in $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup \Gamma$ and we need to take into account the two boundary conditions on $\Gamma$, right?

Comment: Yes, I've seen this by looking at the simplest 1D case. In general, I'm not sure it would be well-posed. Is it a physics problem?

Comment: @JeanDuchon Yes these problems come from physics.

Comment: Nevertheless, are you sure there is a variational formulation? I can see how the problem amounts to a fix point problem (value on $\Gamma$ $\mapsto$ solution of Dirichlet problem in $\Omega_1$ $\mapsto$ $\partial u/\partial n$ on $\Gamma$ $\mapsto$ solution of Neumann problem in $\Omega_2$ $\mapsto$ value on $\Gamma$). That's a method for analysis, but not an answer to the question...